# why do the calculator buttons still respond even when the calculator is off?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
//function for displaying values
function dis(val) {
  document.getElementById("edu").value += val
}
//function for evaluation
function solve() {
  let x = document.getElementById("edu").value
  // eval() is a gobal function in JavaScript and has a defined purpose of solving JavaScript codes.
  let y = eval(x)
  document.getElementById("edu").value = y
}
//function for clearing the display
function clr() {
  document.getElementById("edu").value = ""
}
// var switch 

/*function toggleState(item)
{
            if(item.className == "on") 
            {
            item.className="off";
            } else 
            {
            item.className="on";
            }
      }*/


// <script type="text/javascript">
function onoff() {
  currentvalue = document.getElementById('onoff').value;
  if (currentvalue == "Off") {
    document.getElementById("onoff").value = "On";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("onoff").value = "Off";
  }
}
```

```css
.title {
  border-radius: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
  color: purple;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

input[type="button"] {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: pink;
  color: black;
  border-color: purple;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="text"] {
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: pink;
  border-color: black;
  width: 97%
}

.on {
  background: blue;
}

.off {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calculator Using JS </title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
  <div class=title>WE(LAB)-ASSIGNMENT-1</div>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <!-- <td><input type="button" value="c" onclick="clr()"/> </td> -->
      <td style="width: 200px" ; colspan="5"><input type="text" id="edu" name="edu" disabled />
        <!-- <input type="text" name="display" id="display" disabled> -->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- creating buttons and assigning values-->
      <td><input type="button" value="1" onclick="dis('1')" /> </td>
      <td><input type="button" value="2" onclick="dis('2')" /> </td>
      <td><input type="button" value="3" onclick="dis('3')" /> </td>
      <td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="dis('+')" /> </td>
      <td><input type="button" value="On" id="onoff" onclick="onoff();"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="4" onclick="dis('4')" /> </td>
      <td><input type="button" value="5" onclick="dis('5')" /> </td>
      <td><input type="button" value="6" onclick="dis('6')" /> </td>
      <td><input type="button" value="-" onclick="dis('-')" /> </td>
      <td><input type="button" value="AC" onclick="clr()" /> </td>
      <!-- clr() function will call clr to clear all value -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="7" onclick="dis('7')" /> </td>
      <td><input type="button" value="8" onclick="dis('8')" /> </td>
      <td><input type="button" value="9" onclick="dis('9')" /> </td>
      <td><input type="button" value="*" onclick="dis('*')" /> </td>
      <td><input type="button" value="!" onclick="dis('!')" /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="." onclick="dis('.')" /></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="0" onclick="dis('0')" /> </td>
      <td><input type="button" value="/" onclick="dis('/')" /> </td>
      <!-- <td><input type="button" class="operator" name="Modulus" value="%" onclick="calculator.edu.value += '%'"></td> -->
      <td><input type="button" value="%" onclick="dis('%')" /> </td>
      <td><input type="button" value="=" onclick="solve()" /> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I add on/off button in calculator (using html and javascript) so that if it's on, then we can able to press any other buttons and can't press any other button otherwise. I am adding on/off function but the problem is that if the button is in any condition on/off the other button are being press.

Comment: Hello Fatima can you please change the google drive link to the actual code you know you can also post your code inside of a question.

Comment: please guide me how I add code

Comment: Ok 

so first you'll click on the edit option below the question

then copy/paste your code in the question

and then select all of that code with your mouse and after that click on the curly braces button on top of the textarea.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would use the [<button>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) element instead of the [<input>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) element.

You want the `input` HTML elements to be [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefdisabled) according to a condition (If the user clicked on *OFF*).

When the user toggles between On/Off, JS will go through **all** the relevant input elements and either together enable or disable them.
This can be achieved with this code:

```
function onoff()
{
    const powerBtn = document.getElementById('onoff');
    const powerOn = powerBtn.value === "Off";
    if(powerOn)
    {
        powerBtn.value="On";

    }
    else
    {
        powerBtn.value="Off";
    }
    const htmlCollection = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    const inputElements = [...htmlCollection];

    inputElements.filter(input => input !== powerBtn) // we don't want to affect the toggle button itself which is also an input
        .forEach(input => input.disabled = !powerOn);
}
```

Comment: how I am toggled it via ON/OFF

Comment: can you edit my code so from here I can understand it

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it would be:

- declare 'currentvalue' at the top of the script before putting it into a function using var - by using a var outside of a function, you are allowing it to be accessed anywhere in the script.
- create if statements on each function so that the relevant code will only fire if 'currentvalue' is 'On.

here is an idea of the code:

```
var currentvalue = "Off";

function dis(val) {
        if(currentvalue == "On")
        document.getElementById("edu").value += val
    }
```

Repeat the if statement for each of your functions.

I am not sure if this is the most eloquent of solutions but it works.